# BIGQUERY Running total with ARRAY Object

Tags: google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

I have a Sample Dataset like below

```
WITH S AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS ID2, 'A' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS ID2, 'A' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 2 AS ID2, 'A' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID, 2 AS ID2, 'B' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS ID, 3 AS ID2, 'B' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS ID, 3 AS ID2, 'C' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE
),
S2 AS
(SELECT 
ID2, CODE, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM S
GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT ID2, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(CODE, VALUE)) FROM S2
GROUP BY 1
```

I need to get the running total of ARRAY Elements embedded in the output.
My Current And Expected Outputs are as below:

```
Current Output:                 
Row ID2 f0_.CODE    f0_.VALUE       
1   3   C           10      
        B           10      
2   2   B           10      
        A           10      
3   1   A           20      

Expected Output:                    
Row ID2 f0_.CODE    f0_.VALUE   f1_.CODE    f1_VALUE
1   1   A           20          A           20
2   2   B           10          B           10
        A           10          A           30
3   3   C           10          C           10
        B           10          B           20
                                A           30
```

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH S AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS ID2, 'A' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS ID2, 'A' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS ID, 2 AS ID2, 'A' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS ID, 2 AS ID2, 'B' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS ID, 3 AS ID2, 'B' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS ID, 3 AS ID2, 'C' AS CODE, 10 AS VALUE
), S1 AS (
  SELECT A.ID2, B.CODE, MAX(A.ID) ID 
  FROM S AS A CROSS JOIN S AS B
  GROUP BY ID2, CODE
), S2 AS (
  SELECT ID2, CODE, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE, MAX(ID) ID
  FROM S
  GROUP BY ID2, CODE
), S3 AS (
  SELECT S1.ID2, S1.CODE, IFNULL(S2.VALUE, 0) VALUE, IFNULL(S2.ID, S1.ID) ID
  FROM S1 LEFT JOIN S2 
  USING(ID2, CODE)
), S4 AS (
  SELECT ID2, CODE, VALUE, SUM(VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY ID) TOTAL
  FROM S3 
), S5 AS (
  SELECT ID2, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(CODE, VALUE)) arr1, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(CODE, TOTAL)) arr2
  FROM S4 
  GROUP BY ID2 
)
SELECT ID2,
  ARRAY(SELECT item FROM UNNEST(arr1) item WHERE item.VALUE != 0),
  ARRAY(SELECT item FROM UNNEST(arr2) item WHERE item.TOTAL != 0)
FROM S5
ORDER BY ID2
```

gives you

```
Row     ID2     f0_.CODE    f0_.VALUE   f1_.CODE    f1_.TOTAL    
1       1       A           20          A           20   
2       2       A           10          A           30   
                B           10          B           10   
3       3       B           10          A           30   
                C           10          B           20   
                                        C           10
```